# How to extract Hibernate DB records with Spring initialized in main method of the application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to convert code from https://github.com/mattnworb/hibernate-sample

so that it would not run from test directory, but from **src** dir, as a class with method **main**. In tests the **dbunit** database in xml file is correclty read.

I can see several problems with transforming tests to app:

1. Tests are run with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and test classes extend AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests. Applying this to class with main method resulted in context initialization exception.
2. In Java main method is always static. If I try to inject fields like

`@Autowired
    private SomeClass instance;`

Then I cannot call it in main class, since injected field is not static (and cannot be)

What could be the solution?

Comment: It’s spring boot application ?

Comment: No. Do I need to go Spring Boot? I don't need Tomcat in my application

Comment: No this is fine

Comment: Added answer please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create application context object in your main class and get there bean :

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(“your.package.of.beans”);
 // you are passing here the package where beans  are located  

  YourClass yourClass = ctx.getBean(YourClass.class);
```